# Input shape for embedding layer

Tags: keras, neural-network, nlp, sequence, embedding

I have a question regarding this example:

```py
from numpy import array
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Embedding

sentences = ["Programming is a good habit",
            "This is bad code you must improve it",
            "This is a perfect idea",
            "Your code was clean and neat",
            "You are excellent programmer",
            "You have performed badly in the examinations",
            "You could have made it better",
            "Good work! Keep it up.",
            "Poor performance",
            "Improve yourself"]
#define remarks
remarks = array([1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0])

# integer encode the sentences
vocabulary_size = 60
encoded_sequence = [ one_hot(s, vocabulary_size) for s in sentences ]
print( encoded_sequence )

# pad documents to a max length of 10 words
max_length = 9
padded_sequence = pad_sequences( encoded_sequence, maxlen = max_length, padding='pre' )
print( padded_sequence )

# define the model
model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocabulary_size, 15, input_length = 9)
#embedding_layer = Embedding(vocabulary_size, 15)
model.add(embedding_layer )
model.add( Flatten() )
model.add( Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') )
# compile the model
model.compile( optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'] )
# summarize the model
print( model.summary() )
```

The last line of the code will print:

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding_4 (Embedding)     (None, 9, 15)             900       
                                                                 
 flatten_4 (Flatten)         (None, 135)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 136       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,036?
Trainable params: 1,036
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

That means the weight matrix in the embedding layer has either the shape (15x60) or (60x15)

we can try to fit the model using this line and the code will run without issues
`model.fit(padded_sequence, remarks, epochs=50, verbose=0)`

My question is that the input encoded_sequence has the shape (10 x 9). How that input is multiplied by the embedding matrix with the shape (15x60) or (60x15)? to generate an output embedding of shape (9x15)?. If no multiplication is done, what is the differentiable mathematical equation that related the input and the embedding weight matrix?

I expect that the input should be of the shape (input_length x vocabulary size). For example (9x60) and the weight matrix has the shape (vocabulary size x  15) and the output will have the shape (9x15) as expected.

If the input is converted from (10x9) to (9 x 60)  how is that done?